# Filling up muliple drop Downs with one array

Tags: javascript, html

hello guys i have a simple problem the has  me stumped. i really dont know what do do. I have a function like so.

```
     function getThevalues(data) {
     for (var i = 1; i < data.d.length; i++) {

         MystartingLocation[i] = {}
         MystartingLocation[i]["locName"] = {}
         MystartingLocation[i]["locNode"] = {}

                var Opts  = document.createElement("option");
                var Opt = document.createElement("opo");
                MystartingLocation[i]["locNode"] = data.d[i].locNode;
                MystartingLocation[i]["locName"] = data.d[i].locName;
                Opts.text = data.d[i].locName;
                //Opt.text = data.d[i].locName;
                try {
                    document.getElementById("StartLocations").options.add(Opts);
                    document.getElementById("EndLocations").options.add(Opts);

                 }
       catch (e) {console.log(e);}


     }
 }
```

I'm trying to fill both the start location and the endlocation drop down list with the same values yet every attempt that i have try only fills one of them the endlocation one. What I'm i doing wrong? can someone please point me in the right direction.
Thanks
Miguel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't add the same element to both places in the document.

You need to either create two `option` elements or clone the one you have.

```
document.getElementById("EndLocations").options.add(Opts.cloneNode(true));
```

---

Using two `option` elements would look like this:

```
 function getThevalues(data) {
     for (var i = 1; i < data.d.length; i++) {

         MystartingLocation[i] = {}
         MystartingLocation[i]["locName"] = {}

         var OptA = document.createElement("option");
         var OptB = document.createElement("option");

         MystartingLocation[i]["locNode"] = data.d[i].locNode;

         OptA.text = data.d[i].locName;
         OptB.text = data.d[i].locName;

         try {
             document.getElementById("StartLocations").options.add(OptA);
             document.getElementById("EndLocations").options.add(OptB);
         }
         catch (e) {console.log(e);} 
     }
 }
```

Comment: thank you i even try creating to separate options but it does not seem to work the cloneNode Method you showed above worked like a charm!THanks a million. I will mark the answer correct in 7 minutes.

Comment: Great! I'm glad it worked for you. I think you should use `cloneNode` here instead of making two elements, but just to help you understand it better, I have updated my answer to show how making two elements would work.

Answer (score 3):

You're taking the same child, and moving it.

```
document.getElementById("StartLocations").options.add(Opts);
document.getElementById("EndLocations").options.add(Opts);
```

The `Opts` variable is added to `StartLocations` and then pulled from there and added to `EndLocations`.

You can see this happening if you comment out the second line, and run your code:

```
document.getElementById("StartLocations").options.add(Opts);
//document.getElementById("EndLocations").options.add(Opts);
```

You need to create two different `<option>` elements, and attach each individually.

---

In action:

```
function getThevalues(data) {
    var optStart;
    var optEnd;

    for (var i = 1; i < data.d.length; i++) {
        optStart = document.createElement("option");
        optEnd= document.createElement("option");

        optStart.text = data.d[i].locName;
        optEnd.text = data.d[i].locName;

        document.getElementById("StartLocations").options.add(Opts);
        document.getElementById("EndLocations").options.add(Opts);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for the lines

```
MystartingLocation[i]["locName"] = {}
MystartingLocation[i]["locNode"] = {}
```

because it will be nesting an object inside an object

Comment: I believe my answer will definitely need an edit, can you post the structure of your `data` as well

Comment: atif Im a bit of a need freak. there is a reason for having the object within an object in this particular case. thanks for response.

Comment: According to `MystartingLocation[i]["locNode"] = data.d[i].locNode;`, it looks like `data.d[i].locNode` is a string, but in your data structure `MystartingLocation[i]["locNode"] = {}` you are declaring it as an object. I might be wrong, can you post your `data` response here?